# Cambiar el órden de el código generado por Netbeans / Coolbeans

Tags: netbeans, java-swing, coolbeans

Pasé mi proyecto por codacy y me marca la incidencia

> Fields should be declared at the top of the class, before any method declarations, constructors, initializers or inner classes.

Y lo que pasa es que el netbeans los genera en la parte inferior de mis `JFrame`, ¿Hay alguna forma de cambiar e órden de las declaraciones para que los campos se generen en la parte superior de la clase?

### Intentos

Primero fui a `Tools > Templates`

[image: Netbeans opción templates dentro del menú tools]

posteriormente a la sección `Swing GUI Forms` y seleccioné `JFrame  Form` y dí click en el botón `Open in Editor`

[image: opción abrir en editor del template manager]

agregué un espacio, un comentario o cualquier cosa, **este paso es importante**

Se creará un archivo en tu sistema de ficheros, para ver la ruta ve al panel de propiedades

[image: ruta generada]

Arrastré en netbeans el archivo para editarlo, los comentarios tienen unos caracteres que no se podían ver que hacían que no fueran editables, pero ahora que no cargó el archivo `.form` podemos verlas, simplemente resta pasar a la parte superior

```
public class ${name} extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
```

guardar y veremos que en la plantilla ya no son editables

[image: coentarios no editables cambiados de lugar]

si creo una nueva forma desde cero funcionará, pero al modificar algo en mi forma los cambios no se aplican.

¿Qué puedo hacer al respecto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras un experimento medio loco en el edité  el archivo java,

tal parece que si importar como le hagas el lugar donde encuentre

```
// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
```

Es el lugar donde generará las variables sin importar como esté definido el template.

En mi caso me tocó mover a mano los campos, pero tengo la seguridad de que el generador de código no me los cambiará de lugar.

Por si alguien ocupa modificar la sintaxis de os templates, les dejo la liga de un [tutorial](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-filetemplates.html) para poderlo persnalzar.