# Porque en este JFrame esta parte del codigo esta bloqueada por default?

Tags: java, jframe, interface, netbeans-11, matisse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tal y como veis, he creado un jframe y he ido editando la interfaz con la opción de diseño de netbeans. He añadido una imagen como icono de un label y por default se ha agregado ese codigo. El caso es que me gustaría editar ese código de forma manual pero no puedo porque esta bloqueado. Hay alguna forma de desbloquearlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque NetBeans crea un archivo (creo recordar que tiene formato [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) con extensión `.form`) donde define el diseño de la interfaz gráfica y a partir de este genera ese código que vez bloqueado. Si te dejara modificar dicho código libremente se rompería el proceso de convertir en código el diseño de la GUI que haz hecho gráficamente.

Eso es de las cosas que no me gustan de la herramineta de diseño para SWING de NetBeans. Recuerdo que cuando usaba esta tecnología (ahora prefiero por mucho [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx)) utilizaba un plugin para [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) que era capaz de convertir directamente lo que diseñabas a código Java y viceversa: [windowbuilder](/questions/tagged/windowbuilder).

Comment: aa de acuerdo, muchas gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí una explicación un poco más amplia que la del otro compi, espero no se arme la robación de puntos :v

Básicamente está bloqueada porque siempre se va a regrenerar esa parte... no, ¡Es en serio! Si abres tu archivo digamos con block de notas o un <strike>sh*t</strike>eclipse y luego le haces alguna modificación tus cambios se perderán. OMG!

Bueno es su forma de los de netbeans de hacer su editor gráfico a prueba de tontos (sin agraviar a quien se haya sentido identificado).

Básicamente todo lo que esté dentro de

```
// <editor-fold>//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
Como esto
// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
```

Será código no editable, si quieres jugarle una broma pesada a alguien que use netbeans, puedes ponerle eso en su archivo y se la pasará verdaderamente mal por no poder modificarlo.

Los otros valores que están en la etiqueta sirven para:

- defaultstate - Forma en que se muestra el bloque por defecto

  - collapsed - colapsado
  - expanded - expandido
- desc

  - descripción cuando está colapsado

Ahora lo que realmente hace que no sea editable es la parte de

```
//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
//GEN-END:initComponents
```

Lo que viene después de los dos puntos puede variar, pero cuando dice initComponents, esa parte del código siempre se va a regenerar

#### ¿Qué pasa si le borramos eso?

Simplemente se abrirá todo el código [como solo lectura](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FormGuardedBlockError).

### ¿Quiere eso decir que si quiero personalizar la creación de mis componentes no puedo?

Para nada Hay varias fases en la creación en la que puedes personalizar tu código, solamente necesitas seleccionar el elemento gráfico de tu preferencia, ir al tab de propiedades, ir al tab **code** y elegir la fase en la que quieras.

[image: tab de código en el panel de propiedades]

Las fases como podrás haber notado son:

- creación personalizada
- pre creación
- post creación
- pre inicialización
- post inicialización
- post escuchas
- pre agregación
- post agregación
- pre poblado
- post poblado
- después de que todo esté configurado
- pre declaración
- post declaración

Un código donde puedes apreciar cada parte de un panel es el siguiente:

```
package es.stackoverflow.com.questions358879;

/**
 *
 * @author Ruslan Lopez Carro
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        // pre creación
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel(); // creación personalizada;
        // post creación
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // pre inicialización
        //post inicialización
        jPanel1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel1MouseEntered(evt);
            }
        });
        //post escuchas

        jButton1.setText("botón");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("label");

        // pre poblado

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addContainerGap(212, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(113, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        // post poblado

        // pre agregado

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(103, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(93, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        //post agregado
        // todo configurado

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jPanel1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // pre declaración
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    //post declaración
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

### ¿Puedo controlar dónde se va a generar el código?

Sí, al respecto lee esta otra pregunta mía: [Cambiar el órden de el código generado por Netbeans / Coolbeans](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287428/cambiar-el-%c3%b3rden-de-el-c%c3%b3digo-generado-por-netbeans-coolbeans)